# Why does a grammar checker want to replace "the key to have" with "the key to having"?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositional-phrases

I have written the sentence but grammarly.com says that you need to change "have" to "having".

> The key to <s>have</s> **having** a successful marriage is to remain calm during
> conflicts because it is nearly impossible to patch things up after a
> couple break up.

Why is "have" wrong here?

Comment: Of course, "the key to have is the silver one - it unlocks this door" is perfectly acceptable, but it's a different usage.

Comment: 'having' denotes a continued state.

Comment: "having" is a noun.

Comment: Note that, although your grammar-checker was right in this case, you can't rely on that; grammar-checkers are very often wrong. So instead of asking *why* "have" is wrong, it would have been better to ask *whether* "have" is wrong, and *if so* why.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The idiom is "The key to something", with "to" being a preposition, used idiomatically instead of "for". So we say "the key to the door" or "the key to my heart".

So after "the key to ..." we need the object of the preposition "to", this can be a noun or a gerund, but not a verb.  So "The key to having..." is correct, "the key to have...." is not correct.

Don't think that "to" always marks an infinitive. Sometimes it is just a preposition.

Comment: Note that a gerund *is* a noun: it is a noun derived from a verb.

Comment: I'd rather say a gerund/participle is a gerund/participle. This can distinguish between the gerund "building" and the noun "a building", even though the noun has clearly been formed from the participle.  But gerunds can be the subjects or objects in a  sentencne

Comment: Gerund-participles are verbs! That’s why they can take direct objects and don’t need an ‘of’.

Comment: I still say that gerund/participles are neither nouns, verbs nor adjectives.  They are their own category.

Comment: One can debate endlessly whether gerunds *are* nouns.  But what’s important here is that they *form noun phrases* — the phrase like “having a successful marriage” functions syntactically like a noun.  “Having a successful marriage is important”, “I dream of having a successful marriage”, etc.

Comment: The phrase is similar to "looking forward to seeing you" where to also doesn't mark an infinitive.

Answer (score 1):

"Having a" means that something you "possess" is *on-going* (typically a process):

> I am **having a** very bad day at the office.

Thus,

> the key to *having a* successful marriage

is the same as

> the key to *an ongoing* successful marriage

On the other hand, "have" is something you possess at a point in time:

> I **had** a unsuccessful marriage, but now I **have** a successful marriage, and (hopefully) **will have** a successful marriage.

Merge the *point in time* with the *on-going process* to get:

> I *have had* a successful marriage, and hope to **keep having** a successful marriage.

Comment: This answer is unhelpful. The question is not about semantics: it's about the (unpredictable) syntactic requirements of particular words in English. _Key_ can take an object phrase introduced by the preposition _to_, including one where the object phrase is an _-ing_ clause; it cannot take a _to_-infinitive clause. In this is it is unlike the verb _want_, the adjective _inclined_, and the noun _reason_, all of which can take to-infinitive clauses.

Comment: @ColinFine *"Having a" means that something you "possess" is on-going (typically a process)* is **exactly** why "The key to have a successful marriage" is wrong.  It's your right to see it as unhelpful, but you're wrong.

Comment: As Colin Fine says, this answer is wrong. We *always* say "the key to X-ing" rather than "the key to X", *regardless* of whether we say "I am X-ing" rather than "I X". In fact, your examples demonstrate this: we say "I have a successful marriage", not \*"I'm having a successful marriage".

Comment: @ruakh **at this point in time** "I have a successful marriage".  I **can't know whether it will continue** to be a successful marriage.  Ergo, it is not an on-going process.  What we *can* say, though, is "I hope to *keep having* a successful marriage", which is a continuing process.

Comment: @RonJohn: We can also say "I hope to begin having a successful marriage", "I hope to stop having a successful marriage", and "I hope to remember having a successful marriage". What these all have in common is that, like your examples, not one of them explains why we say "the way to **have** a successful marriage" but "the key to **having** a successful marriage". Because the issue is with the grammar of the word *key*, not the ongoing-ness or not of the successful marriage.

Comment: @ruakh the *point in time* described by "the way to have a successful marriage" and the *ongoing process* described in "the key to having a successful marriage" are perfectly obvious to me.  Probably because I'm broad-minded.

Comment: @RonJohn: the point you are making is valid, but it has absolutely nothing to do with this question. _The key to have a successful marriage_ is ungrammatical (at least for most speakers).

Comment: @ColinFine it's there in black and white (and grey) in my answer as to why "The key to *have* a successful marriage" is ungrammatical: *"have" is something you possess at a point in time*.  It seems that I should clarify that "the key to *verb*" refers to a process, not a point in time.

Comment: "The key to _verb_" doesn't refer to anything, because it is ungrammatical.

Comment: An unhelpful and confusing answer if I ever saw one. The point is, "a key to" must be followed by a noun or something acting as one, in that case a gerund clause. Progressivity has nothing to do with it. "the life to lead" describes a process too, and yet "the life to leading" doesn't mean a thing.